# Scrape content of element with data- attribute - Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the text content which sits behind an a-tag element. The code looks like this:

```
<a data-autid="article-url" href="linkToTheWebsite">HERE STANDS THE TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT</a>
```

In the past these a-tag elements didn't have an "data-" attribute, but a normal "id" attribute, which was super simple to extract. Now I have no idea how this should work. I tried this but it doesn't appear to do the job:

```
self.article_title = item.select_one('a', data_autid='article-url').text.strip()
```

Any idea what I could do?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [`[attr=value]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) CSS Selector:

> Represents elements with an attribute name of *attr* whose value is
> exactly *value*.

---

To use a CSS Selector, use the [`.select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method instead of `find()`.

In your example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<a data-autid="article-url" href="linkToTheWebsite">HERE STANDS THE TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

>>> print(soup.select_one('a[data-autid="article-url"]').text)
HERE STANDS THE TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT
```

---

Or: If you want to use `find()`:

```
print(soup.find("a", attrs={"data-autid": "article-url"}).text)
```

Comment: Sadly none of the both options works. Don't know why. Doesn't give an error or anything, just no content for the variable comes in

Comment: @NiklasKlotz The page is probably loaded dynamically. You should use a module called `selenium` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

html = requests.get('yoururl')
tree = html.fromstring(html.content)
yourtext = tree.xpath('//a[@data-autid="article-url"]/text()')
```

Comment: Why use `lxml`? the OP has tagged `BeautifulSoup`