# Scraping "data" attributes in HTML with Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently learning basic web scraping and I'm curious about `.find()` and if it works with attributes that aren't class or id.

As a practice, I'm trying to get data from the nyc.gov website and export a list of the NYPD precincts + their addresses into a .csv file. In the HTML on the nyc.gov site, the precinct numbers and addresses are labeled as `data-label="Precinct"` and "Address" respectively, but the guide I'm using only shows how to use `class_="etc"` with `.find()`, and I don't know if data attributes are different.

This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://wgetsnaps.github.io/nyc.gov--nypd-videos/html/nypd/html/home/precincts.shtml.html"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
precincts = soup.find_all("td")

numbers = []
addresses = []

for precinct in precincts:
    number = precinct.find("td", data-label_="Precinct").text.strip()
    address = precinct.find("td", data-label_="Address").text.strip()
    numbers.append(number)
    address.append(address)
```

I'll compile it into a dataframe and add an export into .csv later. Jupyter Notebook says, for "data-label_": SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?

I did not mean "==", but I understand its confusion. Any tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrape content of element with data- attribute - Python BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372702/scrape-content-of-element-with-data-attribute-python-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Read and try pandas.read_html : [link]("https://www.scrapehero.com/web-scraping-with-pandas/")

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

df_tables = pd.read_html("http://wgetsnaps.github.io/nyc.gov--nypd-videos/html/nypd/html/home/precincts.shtml.html")
print(df_tables[0])
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). That DF could be easily shown as text, or dumped to CSV. An image eats up bandwidth and is less accessible, among other things.